# How to set document title by React Native Web with react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-web

My web application is created by React Native Web with react-navigator.

react-navigator sets RouteName as document.title in default.

ex.

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="root" component={RootScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="search" component={SearchScreen} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

generates

```html
...
<head>
  <title>root</title>
  ...
```

### What I want

Changing document.title on demand.

### What I tried but not works

try to access document object directly, but below code does not works.

```
export default function RootScreen({ navigation }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `My Web App | ${someMessage}`
  })
```

Comment: More explicit code detail in your question would help lead to an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out that Expo for Web basically sets the screen title as the document title. So I did something like this:

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
const title = (text) => Platform.select({ web: `My Web App | ${text}`, default: text });
```

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="root" component={RootScreen} options={{ title: title('root') }} />
    <Stack.Screen name="search" component={SearchScreen} options={{ title: title('search') }} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

You can then amend the `title` function to return the expected title for your various screens.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to get the name from the app.json, instead of hardcoding it everytime I create a new screen? Where I declare my web configuration (favicon, name...), I set the tab title with the name property. I mean, having ALWAYS the same document title for the web platform

Comment: Setting the title this way works well.
However, it falls down when I have a nested navigation.

Answer (score 14):

This has taken me the best part of my morning to figure out.
There is a way to set the title in one place, rather than on each screen.

```
 <NavigationContainer
    documentTitle={{
      formatter: (options, route) => 
        `${options?.title ?? route?.name} - My Cool App`,
    }}
 >
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/#documenttitle

As you are making this change on the Navigation Container, this also works with nested navigations.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `navigation.setOptions({ title: 'some title' })` within your react components

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/#updating-options-with-setoptions